# Display semi-pseudo code in LaTeX

Tags: latex

How do I type this within LaTeX using lstlisting, or perhaps some other formatting package?

```
E_{T}= \phi ;
sort the edges by their weight, $w(e_1) \le w(e_2) \le \dots \le w(e_m))$;
for (i = 1; i \le m; i = i＋1) {
  if ($T+e_i$ contains no cycles) {
    E_T =E_T+ e_i;
  }
}
```

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com is for you.

Answer (score 1):

Since it looks like pseudo-code, I recommend the [algorithmicx](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/algorithmicx/) package.

Comment: I added "pseudocode" to the question title after this answer.